# How to recognize scroll gesture on top of menu bar in OS X?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, scroll, gesture

I came across an app where in the user can scroll from the top of the screen and it would initiate certain features of the app.

I created a new project and overrode `scrollWheel` in view controller. This seems to work but the scroll has to happen on the window. How can I listen to a scroll gesture on the top of the menu bar ?

Comment: What application does this?

Comment: @dylan Its an app called Unclutter. You can scroll down on the menu bar and it slides down a view.

Comment: I would assume that he uses an invisible window the size and position of the menu bar. Transparent, borderless window without shadow.. but you need to make sure that the menu bar remains working!